# Simple XML Mutiple Array

Tags: java, simple-framework, simple-xml-converter

I am trying to convert that xml to Java POJO but having some issues

```
<betting>
    <over-under status="active" opening="false" date="2022-05-26T19:50:55.243-04:00">
        <id>/betting/odds:259249033</id>
        <sportsbook>fanduel</sportsbook>
    </over-under>
    <over-under status="active" opening="false" date="2022-05-26T13:38:47.437-04:00">
        <id>/betting/odds:259233680</id>
        <sportsbook>22bet</sportsbook>
    </over-under>
    <three-way status="active" opening="false" date="2022-05-26T13:39:30.960-04:00">
        <id>/betting/odds:259233853</id>
        <sportsbook>pinnacle</sportsbook>
    </three-way>
    <three-way status="active" opening="false" date="2022-05-25T23:28:17.967-04:00">
        <id>/betting/odds:259218125</id>
        <sportsbook>betonline</sportsbook>
    </three-way>
</betting>
```

@ElementList is empty

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class Betting {

    @ElementList(name = "over-under", inline = true, required = false)
    private List<OverUnder> overUnders = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<OverUnder> getOverUnders() {
        return overUnders;
    }

    public void setOverUnders(List<OverUnder> overUnders) {
        this.overUnders = overUnders;
    }
}
```

Also when I add second @ElementList for three-way It give me duplicate annotation of name exception.

Any idea ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ElementList(entry = "over-under", inline = true, required = false)
```

works fine.